# RabbitListenerTestHarness injects actual objects in listeners

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

**Scenario:**
Junit for a microservice which listens to a queue and posts to an exchange in rabbitMQ after data extraction.

**Issue:**

> RabbitListenerTestHarness is creating mock object for the Rabbit
>   Listener class alone, Actual objects are being instantiated for
>   Listeners Autowired components

I couldnt find a way to manually inject mock beans into the listener. This causes Junit to post the test messages to the actual queues configured in the microservice during Junit Execution.

**Workaround:** The only way I could use the rabbit-test project is to configure test exchange for posting the messages during Junit execution.

**Query:** 
I wanted to understand, if there is any way better way of writing Junit for a Rabbit Listener. Also i wanted to understand if there is a way to maually inject mock objects to the Rabbit Listeners autowired components.

**Sample code Snippet:**

**Rabbit Listener Class**

```
@RabbitListener(id = "id", bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "sampleQueue", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),key = "sampleRoutingKey", exchange = @Exchange(value = "sampleExchange", durable = "true", ignoreDeclarationExceptions = "true", type = EXCHANGE_TYPE)))
public void getMessageFromQueue(@Payload EventModel event) throws ListenerExecutionFailedException, JAXBException {
    dataExporterService.exportDataAndPostToRabbit(event);
}
```

**Service class**

```
@Autowired
DataExtractorRepository dataExtractorRepository;
@Autowired
DataPublihserRepository dataPublisherRepo;
public void exportDataAndPostToRabbit(EventModel event) throws JAXBException {
        dataPublisherRepo.sendMessageToExchange(dataExtractorRepository.extractOrderData(event), exchangeName, routingKeyValue);
}
```

DataPublihserRepository has rabbitTemplate internally Autowired. DataExtractorRepository connects to DB internally for retriving the message.

**Test class**

```
@Autowired
private RabbitListenerTestHarness harness;

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
@Before
public void setUp() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
DataExporterController = this.harness.getSpy("id");
}

@Test
public void shouldReceiveMessage() throws Exception {
LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer answer = new LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer(1);
doAnswer(answer).when(DataExporterController).getMessageFromQueue(any(EventModel.class));
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("sampleExchange", "sampleRoutingKey", createMessage());
assertTrue(answer.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
verify(DataExporterController, times(1)).getMessageFromQueue(any(OrderEventsModel.class));
verify(orderDataExporterController, times(1)).getMessageFromQueue(any(OrderEventsModel.class));
}

 private Message createMessage() {
        String inputObject = "{\"id\":12345}";
        MessageProperties props = MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance().setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON).build();
        return new Message(inputObject.getBytes(), props);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The harness is intended as a mechanism to verify that the listener received the data in an integration test. To unit test a listener, invoke its `onMessage` Method.

For example, using Mockito, given

```
public class MyListener {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @RabbitListener(id = "myListener", queues = "foo")
    public void listen(Foo foo) {
        this.service.process(foo);
    }

}
```

and

```
public interface SomeService {

    void process(Foo foo);

}
```

then

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class So53136882ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) this.registry
                .getListenerContainer("myListener");
        ChannelAwareMessageListener listener = (ChannelAwareMessageListener) container.getMessageListener();
        Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody("{\"bar\":\"baz\"}".getBytes())
                .andProperties(MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                        .setContentType("application/json")
                        .build())
                .build();
        listener.onMessage(message, mock(Channel.class));
        verify(this.service).process(new Foo("baz"));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRabbit
    public static class config {

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory mockCf() {
            return mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageConverter converter() {
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConnectionFactory(mockCf());
            factory.setMessageConverter(converter());
            factory.setAutoStartup(false);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public MyListener myListener() {
            return new MyListener();
        }

        @Bean
        public SomeService service() {
            return mock(SomeService.class);
        }

    }

}
```

Notice that the container factory does not start the listener container.

For testing publishing, inject a mock `RabbitOperations` which is implemented by `RabbitTemplate`.

For example, given

```
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitOperations rabbitOperations;

    @Override
    public void process(Foo foo) {
        this.rabbitOperations.convertAndSend(
                "someExchange", "someRoutingKey", new Foo(foo.getBar().toUpperCase()));
    }

}
```

and

```
@Bean
public SomeService service() {
    return new SomeServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public RabbitOperations rabbitTemplate() {
    return mock(RabbitOperations.class);
}
```

then

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) this.registry
            .getListenerContainer("myListener");
    ChannelAwareMessageListener listener = (ChannelAwareMessageListener) container.getMessageListener();
    Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody("{\"bar\":\"baz\"}".getBytes())
            .andProperties(MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                    .setContentType("application/json")
                    .build())
            .build();
    listener.onMessage(message, mock(Channel.class));
    verify(this.rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend("someExchange", "someRoutingKey", new Foo("BAZ"));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gary, First off thank you very much for providing detailed insights on how to implement Unit test cases for Rabbit Listener. It really helped me a lot. Also I was trying to inject adviceChain and error Handler in SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory component in the config class, but these clases doesnt seem to be invoked. Is there some configuration required for the same ?

Comment: They are properties of the listener container, and, since we're invoking the listener directly (and not via the container) they are bypassed. It **is** possible to mock the rabbitmq client and inject messages at a lower level in the stack, but it's quite involved. See [this test case for an example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainerTests.java#L178).

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure I will look into it.

Comment: @Jayadeep23 you can also use [rabbitmq-mock](https://github.com/fridujo/rabbitmq-mock) so that you don"t bother with the mocking stuff and things like error handler will be called as in production mode