# Rabbitmq unit test for consumerBatchEnabled listener

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am following the link below to write Junit for rabbit:

[RabbitListenerTestHarness injects actual objects in listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136882/rabbitlistenertestharness-injects-actual-objects-in-listeners)

The only change is that I am consuming the events in batches:

My consumer definition is as below:

```
public class MyListener {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @RabbitListener(id = "myListener", queues = "foo")
    public void listen(List<Messge<Foo>> foo) {
        this.service.process(foo);
    }
}
```

The issue is when I run the Junit test, in rabbitlistener I am expecting `List<Message<Foo>>` whereas I am actually getting `List<Foo>`.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I just tested it and I get a `List<Message<?>>` with or without the harness.

Comment: I was using onMessage(Message message) instead of onMessageBatch((List<Message> list). Works fine now - Thanks